# SQLite Drop Table Help (BlackBerry Webworks)

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry-webworks

I have this function that will drop a table when user exit the app.

```
function emptyTable()
{
  var db = createDatabase();
  var deleteTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblLocalUser";
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(deleteTable, [], goSql, ohSql);
});
}

function goSql()
{
  alert("dropped");
}

function ohSql()
{
  alert("not dropped");
}
```

It works fine on the Ripple Emulator, the table is dropped and the goSql callback function is being executed.

But when I installed the app into the device(9900) the table is not dropped and the callback does not get executed not even the one that display error.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a difference in Javascript run-time evaluator.  Try changing your empty list constructor to a separate line

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    var myList = new Array();
    tx.executeSql(deleteTable, myList, goSql, ohSql);
});
```

Comment: I have tried replacing [] to myList but on the device the callback still does not get executed.